# how to x-y scatterplot two timeseries objects of unequal length, unequal frequency using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, zoo, scatter-plot

I have multiple time series objects covering different periods of time, with gaps in the data, and with varying frequencies (some hourly data, some 15-minute, some 1-minute).

I'm trying to plot different time series objects against one another in x-y scatterplots - to see if there are obvious correlations, and make 'pretty' plots with ggplot for presentation. Obviously, one can only plot/compare data where it exists for `x` and `y` at the same time.

I'm able to get a quick graphic with base graphics, but would like something more presentable.

for example, this works in base R:

```
require(zoo)
x <- zoo(sort(rnorm(10)),as.POSIXct("2013/07/26")+1:10)
y <- zoo(sort(rnorm(30)),as.POSIXct("2013/07/26")+(1:30)/2)
plot(x,y)
```

and trying to do the same with ggplot fails:

```
data <- rbind(melt(fortify(x),id="Index"),melt(fortify(y),id="Index"))
ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type zoo. Defaulting to continuous
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type zoo. Defaulting to continuous
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:x
```

suggestions on better titles/description are welcome

Comment: I'm confused, didn't you just mean `aes(x=Index,y=value)`? x and y aren't variables in your new data frame, so I'm not sure why you'd try to map aesthetics to them.

Comment: excellent point, the issue then is probably with formatting the data correctly to begin with. perhaps a better question is 'how to prepare unequal length, unequal frequency time series objects for scatterplotting with ggplot2?'

Comment: But haven't you done that? Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: yes, but your suggestion gets me a plot with Index on the x axis, and the values on the y-axis (two time-series, with time on the x-axis), what I want is a comparison of the two, with one time-series on the x-axis, and the other on the y-axis, as in the plot(x,y) in my example, which works

Comment: this gets me close: `b <- cast(data,Index~variable,mean);
ggplot(b,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()`, but i'd prefer using 'identity' instead of 'mean' as the aggregation function...but that fails for some reason

Comment: I think Doctor Dan has a potential option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
aaa<-merge(x,y, all=FALSE)
ggplot(aaa,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()    ?
```

Comment: Instead of `na.omit` you could also use `merge(x,y,all=FALSE)`.